# Simple socket client pair does not respond

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am in the early stages of making a two player game using sockets and serversockets and etc. I have written the game and client and have gotten no compilation errors, but the problem is when they are run. They will connect as I get the message in the console saying connection successful. However, they are suppose to bounce a message back and forth once just to test the connection but it does not. Could someone take a look at it? I do get exceptions when I end one or the other from running as I should. Here is the code:

Server:

```
    public class Server 

{

private ServerSocket listener;

public Server()
{
    try 
    {
        listener = new ServerSocket(25565);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.err.println("Uknown IOException when creating the server socket; " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void startServer()
{
    try
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        while (true)
        {
            Socket socket = listener.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection " + socket.getLocalSocketAddress() + " was accepted!");
            Player player = new Player(socket);
            new Thread(player).start();
            if (game.one == null)
                game.one = player;
            else if (game.two == null)
                game.two = player;
            else 
                player.rejectConnection();

        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Uknown IOException when starting server; " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Server().startServer();
}

class Player implements Runnable
{

    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public Player(Socket socket)
    {
        try
        {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Uknown IOException when creating instance of player; " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void send(String message)
    {
        out.println(message);
    }

    public void rejectConnection() 
    {
        out.println("REFUSECON");
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
                out.println("RECIVED");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Uknown IOException when listening on player; " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class Game
{

    private Player one = null;
    private Player two = null;

    public Game()
    {   
    }


}
```

}

Client:

```
public class Client 
{

    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Client();
    }

    public Client()
    {
        try 
        {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 25565);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            Listener listener = new Listener(socket);
            new Thread(listener).start();
            this.send("Hello World!");
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Uknown UnknownHostException when connecting to the server; " + e.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Uknown IOException when connecting to the server; " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void send(String message)
    {
        out.println(message);
    }


    class Listener implements Runnable
    {

        private BufferedReader in;

        public Listener(Socket socket)
        {
            try 
            {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Uknown IOException when trying to listen client side; " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        public void run()
        {
            String line;
            try 
            {
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line + " - In Client");
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Uknown IOException when trying to listen client side; " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance. I would like you to explain what I am doing wrong please don't just correct it because it is more of learning how to do this than it is making the program work.

Answer (score 0):

PrintWriters don't have automatic flushing enabled. Try `out.flush()` after each `out.println()`. Or, pass `true`  as second argument when you create your PrintWriter.